# Keep selection through all loops vba

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, select

How can I select all slides whose ranges are stored in an array? With a loop it begins all over so only one slide is selected at once. How can I select several specified slides (i.e. the ones with the ranges from the array) with a code? Thank you so much!

```
ReDim arr(1 To 1) As Long    
Dim b As Long    
For b = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
ActivePresentaiton.Slides.Range(arr(b)).Select
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Slides.Range Method with your Array. The following example selects the slides 1, 4 and 5:

```
Sub SlideRangeExample()

    Dim SlideArray(3) As Integer

    SlideArray(1) = 5
    SlideArray(2) = 1
    SlideArray(3) = 4

    ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(SlideArray).Select

End Sub
```

So in your case just replace the `SlideArray` with your array `arr`:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(arr).Select
```

Comment: Haha, I spent so many hours and tried so many things, except this simple line. Thank you so much!

Comment: If it helped you, please consider to accept this as the answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers